# Should we merge [coloring] to/from [graph-colouring]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Currently [graph-colouring](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-colouring) has a large number of questions, and [coloring](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloring) has two questions with no significant difference to those of [graph-colouring](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-colouring). Thus I guess we should merge these two tags.

> Should we perform the merge?

However, which direction should we perform the merge? Personally I like [coloring](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloring) better; since there are other tags like [graph-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) and [graph-algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms), the word "graph" has been used too much since most of the time [coloring](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloring) comes along with those tags.

> What do you think? Which direction should the merge be performed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think graph-coloring (or graph-colouring) is more informative.

Comment: Agreed. We don't want graph colo(u)ring to get mixed up with connector colouring or other kinds of colouring.

Comment: Nice! Should I create a new post for voting to merge [coloring] to [graph-colouring] then? Or we just vote here?

Answer (score 2):

I agree to Suresh.  [graph-colouring](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-colouring) is more informative than [coloring](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloring).

One possible argument against merging the two tags into [graph-colouring](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-colouring) is that it refers to a narrower notion.  Indeed, I can imagine that some users may feel a mental barrier when trying to tag a question about hypergraph coloring as [graph-colouring](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-colouring).  However, I think that this mental barrier is low enough and that questions about hypergraph coloring (or any notions related to graph coloring) can be tagged as [graph-colouring](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-colouring) without much confusion.

By the way, the difference between American and British spellings should be handled by synonyms.

Comment: For practice, do any of the other mods want to create a synonym :) ?

Comment: I'll give it a go. (When I'm actually supposed to be awake, not in the middle of the night remembering tasks that need to be done, though.)

Comment: I did it now anyway.

Comment: Thank you @Dave!